# How to delete model from backbone collection using Firebase

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase, backbonefire

I have a collection from which I would like to delete a model and have it sync in real-time:

```
var ClientCollection = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
  model: Client,
  url: "https://<my-firebase-url>.firebaseio.com",
  autoSync: true
});
```

I have tried the following from the collection veiw using my `clear` function:

```
var ClientView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName:  "li",
  className: "list-group-item",
  template: _.template("<%= name %>"),
  events: {
    "click .destroy" : "clear"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
  clear: function() {
      this.model.remove();
  },
});
```

However this only removes the model from the DOM.

**How do I delete the model from the server AND the DOM?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection view would need to change slightly for it to be deleted from the DOM and server.

Use [**`listenTo`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) to ensure the changes are synced *and* have the model removed from the DOM.

Add the following to your `initialize` function.

```
// This will listen for the destroy method and then remove the item from the dom
this.listenTo(this.model, "destroy", this.remove);
```

And then in the `clear` function use [**`destroy`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy):

```
clear: function() {
    this.model.destroy({success: function(model, response) {
       // Do something if successful
    }});
},
```

---

The full view should be something like this:

```
var ClientView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName:  "li",
  className: "list-group-item",
  template: _.template("<%= name %>"),
  events: {
    "click .destroy" : "clear"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, "destroy", this.remove);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.model.destroy({success: function(model, response) {
      $('.notification').fadeIn(200).html('Success - Item removed').fadeOut(1000);
      return this;
    }});
  },
});
```

---

**The above code works as expected**